# Cx_Oracle : DatabaseError: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Tags: python, oracle12c, cx-oracle

I am facing this error while using Cx_Oracle package in python environment. I upgraded to oracle 12c from 11g but it still gets me this error. Also, I am using ojdbc6.jar.

DatabaseError: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Answer (score 0):

ojdbc6.jar is driver for JVM/Java

Cx_Oracle is C/C++ library depending on libclnth.so library.

The errors states that your client is either to old (or too new) and you can not authenticate to the database. There is no auth protocol that both sides implement/accept.

Either you should upgrade your client or change
sqlnet.ora set `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION` to version of your client library.

Answer (score 0):

From 12c onward, minimum supported version default has changed from 11 to 12 and `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION` is now replaced with the `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER` and `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT` parameters

You need to add these two parameters in your sqlnet.ora file, you can find that file at
`ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/`

After you made the changed, do not forget to reload the listener using `lsnrctl reload`

For more see [Oracle Official Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spuss/check-for-sqlnet-allowed-logon-version-parameter-behavior.html#GUID-433E0DB9-026E-4322-A8FF-BA0E108AB28B)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me while using `cx-Oracle 8.0.1`

add in `sqlnet.ora`

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=11
```

The error disapears, but I got instead

```
ORA-01017: Invalid Username/Password
```

The *workaround* was to *change the password*:

```
alter user UUUUU identified by PWD;
```

After this the user `PASSWORD_VERSIONS`  were set from 10 to 12 and everything worked *fine*!

```
select PASSWORD_VERSIONS  from dba_users where username = 'UUUUU';

PASSWORD_VERSIONS
-----------------
10G 11G 12C
```